# Having feature policy issue with geolocation using ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using Google maps on my ionic project using following code.

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

  let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

  let mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

with above code, I am getting this error.

`Geolocation has been disabled in this document by Feature Policy`

Any idea how can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any iframe involved?

Comment: @charlietfl there is not iframe unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It is because Geolocation API isemoved from unsecured origins. You can solve it by adding appropriate permissions. On Android platform, open your project, search for AndroidManifest.xml and add these lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Comment: I am currently using it on desktop browser using `ionic serve -l` command. Is there a way to put such permission for desktop browsers? And I am also targeting iOS.

Comment: Did you try it out in your real devices?

Comment: Not yet. will give it a try but first I am trying to make it work on desktop if possible.

Comment: There are lots of plugins which wont works in browser. It will required real devices. Geolocation is also one of them. It is better to test this app in real device. Google map API for native app will never allow permission for browsers. Real app works through file system so it might works.

Comment: Thank you for that. Can you please help me with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51742862/ionic-cordova-run-ios-throws-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-unhandled-promise) then?

Comment: Ok i will try to solve this issue too. If it works then dont forget to tick as answer :P