# Geolocation access has been blocked because of a Feature Policy applied to the current document Ionic 3

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3, google-places-api, google-nearby

Please help me to solve this damn problem map will working fine when run on browser but when i run on lab view or apk real device its will show a blank white screen please help to resolve this its been 3 months to find a way to solve this problem. it will very helpfull if some one help to resolve and one more thing if google allow cross origin in iframe how to implement iframe.
and im also you this code

> Error: Geolocation access has been blocked because of a Feature Policy
>   applied to the current document. See goo.gl/EuHzyv for more details

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export MyApp {
  constructor(public plt: Platform) {
    this.plt.ready().then((readySource) => {

      this.getUserPosition();

    });
  }
}
```

instead of this

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.getUserPosition();
}
```

this is my Map.ts

```
    import { Component, ViewChild ,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation ,GeolocationOptions ,Geoposition ,PositionError } from '@ionic-native/geolocation'; 


declare var google;

@Component({
    selector: 'page-map',
    templateUrl: 'map.html'
})
export class MapPage {

@ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;

options : GeolocationOptions;
currentPos : Geoposition;
map: any;
places : Array<any> ;



constructor
(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private geolocation : Geolocation,



    ) {} 



ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.getUserPosition();
}    




getUserPosition(){
    this.options = {
    enableHighAccuracy : false
    };
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.options).then((pos : Geoposition) => {

        this.currentPos = pos;     

        console.log(pos);
        this.addMap(pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude);

    },(err : PositionError)=>{
        console.log("error : " + err.message);
    ;
    })
}

getRestaurants(latLng)
{
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
    let request = {
        location : latLng,
        radius : 3000 ,
        types: ["gym"]
    };
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        service.nearbySearch(request,function(results,status){
            if(status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK)
            {
                resolve(results);    
            }else
            {
                reject(status);
            }

        }); 
    });

}

createMarker(place)
{
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: this.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: place.geometry.location
    });   
}  

ionViewDidload(){
    console.log(MapPage)
}


addMap(lat,long){

    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

    let mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

    this.getRestaurants(latLng).then((results : Array<any>)=>{
        this.places = results;
        for(let i = 0 ;i < results.length ; i++)
        {
            this.createMarker(results[i]);
        }
    },(status)=>console.log(status));

    this.addMarker();
}


addMarker(){

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: this.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: this.map.getCenter()
    });

    let content = "<p>This is your current position !</p>";          
    let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: content
    });
import { Component, ViewChild ,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation ,GeolocationOptions ,Geoposition ,PositionError } from '@ionic-native/geolocation'; 


declare var google;

@Component({
    selector: 'page-map',
    templateUrl: 'map.html'
})
export class MapPage {

@ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;

options : GeolocationOptions;
currentPos : Geoposition;
map: any;
places : Array<any> ;



constructor
(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private geolocation : Geolocation,



    ) {} 



ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.getUserPosition();
}    




getUserPosition(){
    this.options = {
    enableHighAccuracy : false
    };
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.options).then((pos : Geoposition) => {

        this.currentPos = pos;     

        console.log(pos);
        this.addMap(pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude);

    },(err : PositionError)=>{
        console.log("error : " + err.message);
    ;
    })
}

getRestaurants(latLng)
{
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
    let request = {
        location : latLng,
        radius : 3000 ,
        types: ["gym"]
    };
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        service.nearbySearch(request,function(results,status){
            if(status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK)
            {
                resolve(results);    
            }else
            {
                reject(status);
            }

        }); 
    });

}

createMarker(place)
{
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: this.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: place.geometry.location
    });   
}  

ionViewDidload(){
    console.log(MapPage)
}


addMap(lat,long){

    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

    let mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

    this.getRestaurants(latLng).then((results : Array<any>)=>{
        this.places = results;
        for(let i = 0 ;i < results.length ; i++)
        {
            this.createMarker(results[i]);
        }
    },(status)=>console.log(status));

    this.addMarker();
}


addMarker(){

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: this.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: this.map.getCenter()
    });

    let content = "<p>This is your current position !</p>";          
    let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: content
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
    infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
    });

}
}google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
    infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
    });

}
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB8pf6ZdFQj5qw7rc_HSGrhUwQKfIe9ICw&libraries=places"></script>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have a fair share of developing ionic with google map with alot of issues in the past.  Using https://leafletjs.com/ really solved alot of my issues. Maybe u can take a look at it.

Comment: @Gene i'll already used this but same problem occurs always

Comment: I think you have the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51734268/having-feature-policy-issue-with-geolocation-using-ionic) check ou this post.

Comment: @Benyamin Its not working ..